# PHP | How to wait for the page to load? (In a loop)

Tags: php

The PHP code runs many pages at the same time (loop), which is basically the goal.

But as soon as it happens, I notice that my lighttpd webserver freezes, everytime.

Is it possible to add that the code will wait until each page finishes loading?
Page by page slowly, not all together.

My PHP:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++){
file_get_contents("http://website.com/number?1&page$x");}
?>
```

Comment: `file_get_contents()` is not asynchronous. Each call doesn't start until the previous one finishes.

Comment: What is the purpose of this ? The file_get_contents call you show  is not stored in any variable

Comment: @SebastienD I believe it's a minimal test case to request many pages from website.com.

Comment: @Barmar But it looks like all the 100 pages are running at the same time, because the server freezes completely every time. And if I do this manual everything is ok

Comment: what are you doing with the contents of each file you load?

Comment: @SebastienD Just to run the pages, type of cronjob

Comment: @phong That's not possible. They're just really close together, not at the same time.

Comment: @RamRaider Basically, just run the script inside each page. Frequency of several hours

Answer (score 2):

Maybe PHP's "sleep" function will help you. E.g.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++){
    sleep(2);
    file_get_contents("http://website.com/page?1&subpage$x");
}
```

Comment: Did you really mean to sleep almost 9 minutes between each?

Comment: @Herco I immediately check, Thank you! But with 2 seconds instead of 9 minutes

Comment: Wow, I was convinced sleep used milliseconds. Too many different languages I guess, will update my answer.